# Azure Mobile Services table to c# class mismatch: Error: Item identifiers can only be specified via the 'id' property

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I've just refactored my Xamarin Android app that uses Azure Mobile Services as backend. Recently I got this really strange error.

When I try to insert a new item to the database:

```
_client.GetTable<T>().InsertAsync(instance)
```

I then get a MobileServiceInvalidOperationException that goes:

> Error: Item identifiers can only be specified via the 'id' property.

It seems like AMS is not able to match the class properties with the sql table. If I change Id to id then the next issue is that it cannot match __version with my property Version.

However the strange part is that it all works if I insert or read from the table at app startup (which I did before the refactoring). And only one table has this issue.

Does anyone have a clue what it could be? I could do a workaround by reading once at startup, but that's just not satisfying.

Here is the class / table.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using System;

namespace Core.Models
{
    public class PostAction
    {

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; } 
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }

        [CreatedAt]
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [UpdatedAt]
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        [Version]
        public string Version { get; set; }
     }
}
```

Comment: Jan, are you using the .NET or JavaScript backend?

Comment: Yavor, I'm using the JavaScript backend.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the data type from string to int for Id property.

Answer (score 0):

Azure uses strings instead of ints as PKs. I you have old data in your app it might work up to a certain point since SQLite is pretty tolerant in terms of types. BUT at some point eg. if you used foreign key relations you will have to migrate your database.